# Why must I create inputStream and outputStream with type FileReader/Writer when im creating the objects themselves?

Tags: java, io

Ok this is the code and my question is why do i have to put `FileReader inputstream = null;` and the same with `FileWriter`. Why can't I simply create the objects later in the try block? Am I missing something... I probably am.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FileReader inputStream = null;
        FileWriter outputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = new FileReader("In.txt");
            outputStream = new FileWriter("Out.txt");
            int c;
            while ((c = inputStream.read()) != -1){
                outputStream.write(c);

            }
        }
                finally {
                    if (inputStream != null){
                        inputStream.close();
                    }
                    if (outputStream != null){
                        outputStream.close();

                }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you won't be able to refer to them in the `finally` block, and so you won't be able to close them.

Btw, if they are reader and writer, you'd better name the variables that way, rather than `xStream`.

I/O handling has always been tedious, that's why Java 7 introduced ["try with resource"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: thanks, and yea. im on macosx and it is school property so i cant use anything but 6.

Answer (score 0):

Because with `FileReader inputstream = null` you *do not* create an object, just a reference named `inputStream` to one. Which one? None, the reference is initialized with null. Later on you may or may not create an object (but what happens if `new FileReader(...)` throws an exception?); the checks in the finally block need to work on initialized variables.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about the definite assignment rules.  Java will only allow you to use a local variable if it can be guaranteed that the variable has been initialized.

Consider this simplified version of your code:

```
    FileReader inputStream;  // not initialized here ...
    try {
        inputStream = new FileReader("In.txt");
        // do stuff
    } finally {
        if (inputStream != null) {
            inputStream.close();
        }
    }
```

No suppose that the `FileReader` constructor doesn't find the `In.txt` file, and throws a `FileNotFoundException`.  The constructor terminates "abnormally" and no value gets assigned to `inputStream`.  Then we arrive at the `finally` block, where we try to test that `inputStream` is not `null`.  But at that point, `inputStream` is still uninitialized, and Java won't allow us to take the value of an uninitialized local variable and you get a compilation error.

The seemingly useless assignment of `null` to `inputStream` solves the problem by ensuring that the variable has always been initialized when we get to the `finally` block.

---

The Java Language Specification devotes a whole chapter to specifying the definite assignment rules; i.e. the rules that the compiler uses to decide if a variable has been initialized at any given point.  These rules are rather conservative, and in some cases the compiler will say something is not definitely assigned when a big-brained human can deduce that it is.  You just have to live with that, and occasionally add an unnecessary initialization or a `return` statement that can't ever be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I often use the following

```
FileReader in = new FileReader("In.txt");
try {
    // do reading
} finally {
    in.close();
}
```

This means the enclosing method throws an IOException (i.e. FileNotFoundException).
This fits with Java 7 too:

```
try (FileReader in = new FileReader("In.txt"); FileWriter ...) {
    // do reading
}
```