# Exception in the adapter due to poor data connection

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-adapter

I have several stacktraces like the ones below all over my app anytime there is a call to get data from my MySQL DB.  If the connection goes out and it timeouts, I get the following stacktraces:

Example:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:128)
at com.---.---.profile.MyReviewAdapter.<init>(MyReviewAdapter.java:20)
at com.---.---.profile.UserFragmentActivity$CommentFragment$MyCommentTask.onPostExecute(UserFragmentActivity.java:559)
at com.---.---.profile.UserFragmentActivity$CommentFragment$MyCommentTask.onPostExecute(UserFragmentActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Example:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.init(ArrayAdapter.java:310)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:128)
at com.---.---.master.TopItemAdapter.<init>(TopItemAdapter.java:18)
at com.---.---.master.MainFragmentActivity$TopFrag$TopTask.onPostExecute(MainFragmentActivity.java:961)
at com.---.---.master.MainFragmentActivity$TopFrag$TopTask.onPostExecute(MainFragmentActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is a sample code that is being called with this second LogCat:

```
class TopTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
            private MyProgressDialog progressDialog = new MyProgressDialog(
                    getActivity());
            InputStream is = null;
            String result = "";

            protected void onPreExecute() {

                    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                    progressDialog.show();
                    progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {

                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            TopTask.this.cancel(true);

                        }
                    });

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                String url_select = "http://www.---.com/---/master_cat_items.php";

                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_select);
                ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Sort", Sort));

                try {
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

                    // read content
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
                }
                try {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(is));
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = "";
                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();
                    result = sb.toString();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }

                return null;

            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Void v) {

                String item, cat;
                try {
                    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                    JSONObject json_data = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        item = json_data.getString("item");
                        cat = json_data.getString("category");

                        items.add(item);
                        cats.add(cat);

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e1) {

                } catch (ParseException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                                   e.printStackTrace(); 
                                   // toast to notify user to reload

                            }



                TopItemAndTrendingObject[] mco = new TopItemAndTrendingObject[items
                        .size()];
                int index = 0;

                for (@SuppressWarnings("unused")
                String i : items) {
                    mco[index] = new TopItemAndTrendingObject(items.get(index),
                            cats.get(index));
                    index++;
                }

                adapter = new TopItemAdapter(getActivity(), mco); // this is what is referenced in LogCat
                setListAdapter(adapter);


                progressDialog.dismiss();


            }
        }
```

So my questions are:

1. What does this exception mean(yes, I know what a NullPointerException is)?
2. **More importantly, how can I prevent this?**  Even if it is as basic as throwing a toast when connection drops(anything instead of a force close?

**Edit:  Code for `TopItemAdapter` as requested**

```
public class TopItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TopItemAndTrendingObject> {
    private final Context context;

    public TopItemAdapter(Context context, TopItemAndTrendingObject[] items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
        this.context = context;

    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView tv1;
        public TextView tv2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        View rowView = convertView;
        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            rowView = inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.master_cat_all_time, null, true);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv1 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.myMastCat_Cat);
            holder.tv2 = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.myMasterCat_Item);

            rowView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        TopItemAndTrendingObject mco = getItem(position);
        String item = mco.item;
        String cat = mco.cat;

        holder.tv2.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1) + ". " + item);
        holder.tv1.setText(cat);

        return rowView;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code for the `TopItemAdapter`?

Comment: That `NullPointerException` in the initialization of an `ArrayAdapter` can happen in two cases: the array trat you pass in the adapter is `null`(not your case) or the `Context` you return from `getActivity` is `null`. So  I doubt the error appears because of a dropped MySql connection as this would have raised problems much earlier that the initialization of the adapter. Can you share more details about how you use the `AsyncTask` in the context of your fragments?

Comment: @Luksprog well, It is a `FragmentActivity` using support library and `viewpager`.  This Main Activity has three tabs -- all "inner" static ListFragments.  The one where this error is occurring is in the third fragment which is first instantiated like `new TopTask().execute();`  inside the `onActivityCreated`.  does this help?

Comment: @Luksprog One more comment: Why can't my array be null due to no connection? When this drops out after the `ProgressDialog` spins for a while (the first sign of trouble), the screen is always blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does this exception mean

As I already said in my comments that `NullPointerException` doesn't appear because the database connection fails(in which case a different error would have occurred and also much faster), it appears because you didn't take in consideration the way Android uses activities and fragments(more precisely their lifecycle).

I don't know if you have extra details about those exceptions, my guess is that the exception appears when a user goes to the problematic `Fragment` sees the `ProgressDialog`(and the task is started) and then rotates the phone. At this moment Android will recreate the activity along with any of the containing fragments. This should be handled by your code but, instead, you did something in particular bad, that will throw the `NullPointerException`.

Looking at the way you declared the `TopTask` class is safe to say it's an inner class in the `Fragment`. Being an inner class means that it has a "connection" to the enclosing `Fragment` instance allowing it to use the fragment's methods(like `getActivity()`). So the user goes to the `Fragment`, the task is started and then rotates the phones. At this time the activity and the fragments will be recreated, but your task(which is still running) will keep the special reference to the initial fragment(which is dead by now). After rotation this initial fragment reference will be detached from an activity and its `getActivity` method will return `null`. Passing `null` to an `ArrayAdapter`(in your case through the a `super` call) will throw the exceptions you see(which come from a device with `ICS`). The array that you pass to the adapter can't be `null` as you declare it right above the adapter's initialization. This will also throw a different exception.

> More importantly, how can I prevent this? Even if it is as basic as throwing a toast when connection drops(anything instead of a force close?

The simplest thing to do is to not destroy the fragments along configuration changes. This is done by using the [`setRetainInstance(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setRetainInstance%28boolean%29) method of a `Fragment` so the reference to the `Fragment` will be kept valid(in the `onCreate` callback for the `Fragment` for example). I would also make the `TopTask` class as a static class and pass a reference to the `Fragment` in the constructor of the `TopTask`. This should be tested.

You could also send a reference to the application context from the `Fragment` to the `TopTask` like this(but maybe you should avoid it) which will be valid:

```
// in the onActivityCreated method
new TopTask(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).execute(/*parameters*/);
```

Also keep the reference for the `ProgressDialog` but initialize it in the `onPreExecute` callback.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  A lot of effort into that.  I will almost certainly mark this correct after I check a couple things out.  I can tell you, the problem happens more when the ProgressDialog is interrupted or canceled by the user than when orientation changes.  For example, often times when there is a connection issue, the user gets frustrated and cancels dialog in mid-cycle.  Usually force close.  This doesn't happen when it is always canceled, but only when there is a connection issue which is why I was led to believe that was the issue.

Comment: I am going to add `setRetainInstance(true)`  - Would I put this in each of my three inner fragments inside their `onActivityCreated` method (at very bottom of this method)?

Comment: @KickingLettuce Yes, you could put it in the `onActivityCreated`. I don't see why that behavior with the `ProgressDialog`(which by the way I wouldn't make cancelable, if the user want to see the data he should wait or do something else) should trigger a null context in the adapter. Also, check the documentation for that method, the fragment's lifecycle methods will still be called so be careful how you initialize the data(for example if the the task is running and the user rotates the screen you may start a new task if you just use `new TopTask().execute` in `onActivityCreated`)

Comment: @KickingLettuce Also, your TopTask isn't very well designed, for instance if there is an exception with the `InputStream` you still try to read something from it with the `BufferedReader` object instead of cancelling future work. Another thing, is that you don't check in any way if the `doInBackground` has finished  its job properly, you use the data no matter what.

Comment: thank you again. setRetainInstance seems to have dramatically helped! if you can add any basic code about checking doInBackground like you say That would be great, if not thanks for your help on the original issue.

Comment: @KickingLettuce See this https://gist.github.com/3891421 . The changes aren't big, just wrap the potential dangerous code in a try - catch block to prevent the task from crashing along your app. If anything goes wrong your adapter would just have 0 elements. Not very intuitive for the user but at least the app will not crush.

Comment: It's several months later but I am finally understanding what you are saying here.  I'm still having issues with this but at least i UNDERSTAND what is happening.  This mainly happens now when `task` is running, and user interrupts and activity is killed. (Back to previous screen, etc.). Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 1):

1. What a NullPointer Exception is can you read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)
2. I think, first of all, you should initialize your objects right and not with null. For example:

   ```
   InputStream is = null;
   ```

do it like this:

```
InputStream is = new InputStream();
```

You have more than just one object initialized with null!

**Edit:**

I think the problem is here:

```
try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json_data = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    item = json_data.getString("item");
                    cat = json_data.getString("category");

                    items.add(item);
                    cats.add(cat);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e1) {

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

do it like this:

```
try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                JSONObject json_data = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    json_data = new JSONOBject(jArray.getJSONObject(i).toString());
                    item = json_data.getString("item");
                    cat = json_data.getString("category");

                    items.add(item);
                    cats.add(cat);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e1) {

            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

And catch also all Exception not only JSONException and ParseException.

Comment: Well it says it can'ts instaitate type InputStream... so I could ot do this: `InputStream is = new InputStream();`  I did add Exception after all other exceptions, I think that might be a good idea.  I will report back on that after I test more!

Comment: Sorry, I still get the same error.   I finished up with  `} catch (Exception e) {` as the final "catch all".  Any other thoughts?

Comment: initializing with null is common practice and has its reasons e.g allowing you to close in a `finally` block.

Comment: @vikki yeah it is possible to initialize with null for some exceptions... but in normal cases you should avoid the initialisation with null!

Comment: In this particular case it is [best](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416302/why-must-i-create-inputstream-and-outputstream-with-type-filereader-writer-when) to initialized to null.

Answer (score 1):

If your main concern is just Force Close and you want your App never show Force Close then you can use UncaughtExceptionHandler.

```
public class UncaughtExceptionHandler implements java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler
{
    private final Context myContext;

public UncaughtExceptionHandler(Context context) {
    myContext = context;
}

public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable exception) {


    StringWriter stackTrace = new StringWriter();
    exception.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stackTrace));
    System.err.println(stackTrace);

    Intent intent = new Intent(myContext, AnyActivity.class);
    myContext.startActivity(intent);

    Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
    System.exit(10);
}
}
```

and write this line before **setContentView** in your **Activity**

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler  (this));
```